# How can insert resource string in view.xml from appcelerator (alloy)

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

In one appcelerator application I have create a resource file of string (string.xml). In this file I have put any resource like this:

```
<string name="en_clinical_document">Treatments</string>
```

and in my controller .js I set the text of the label in this mode:

```
$.label.text= L("en_clinical_document");
```

this code works, but how can I use the same method in **View.XML**?

for example, I have this:

```
<Label id="labelRegistry"></Label>
```

and I want insert the content of en_clinical_document in labelregistry.

It is possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

[EDITED: warning, it doesn't work]

from the [internationalization](https://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization) documentation

> you can use the titleid property of Titanium UI objects, such as labels or buttons, to directly reference a string resource without using the L() macro.

```
var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    titleid: 'welcome_message'
});
/*
* is equivalent to
*   var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({
*   text: L('welcome_message')
* });
*/
```

So I guessed in view's xml one could use the titleid attribute, like

```
<Label titleid="welcome_message"></Label>
```

but, after some tests, I've found it does not work as expected, neither in the XML, nor creating plain js Ti.UI object: the following snippet only showing the first `labelA`

```
    var labelA = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        top: 100,
        text: L('welcome_message'),
        backgroundColor:"green",
        font: {
            fontSize: "50dp"
        }
    });

    var labelB = Ti.UI.createLabel({
        top: 200,
        titleid: 'welcome_message',
        backgroundColor:"red",
        font: {
            fontSize: "50dp"
        }
    });

    $.index.add(labelA);
    $.index.add(labelB);

    $.index.open();
```

So it appears that the documented functionality provided by `titleid`is no longer available.

Comment: thanks for your response but in xml file not works that code

Comment: you're welcome, and sorry if it's not a solution, It surprise me though, as I found an expected  `$.__views.labelRegistry = Ti.UI.createLabel({ id: "labelRegistry", titleid: "en_clinical_document"  });` in the Alloy compiled controller in Resources. I'd go with a complete test then, just to try to figure out what's wrong with it.